# Mapped keys do not work in some applications

Tags: apple, xmodmap, xkb

I have an Apple keyboard where the right command key (`Super_R`) is mapped to the right Alt key (`ISO_Level3_Shift`) with `xmodmap`:

```
$ cat ~/.Xmodmap 
clear mod4
keysym Super_R = ISO_Level3_Shift
```

In some applications though, like Firefox and Thunderbird, the right Command and Alt keys are disabled altogether. Is my `.Xmodmap` invalid?

I have also tried redefining keycodes in section `xkb_keycodes` of a dump from `xkbcomp` and then loading the keymap with `xkbcomp` but still no luck with Firefox and Thunderbird. Any clues?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This neat command solves the problem:

```
setxkbmap -option lv3:rwin_switch
```